# Can I get the value from the key from ng-repeat x in xx | unique x.key

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a collection of items that represent a grouping by one property. I want to create a list of items grouped by the value of this property and in each list present the value of this group once and then all the items that belong to the group.

Something like the following

```
<div ng-repeat="items in itemcollection | unique: 'groupkey'">
  <h3>{{items.groupkey}}</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <label>{{item.name}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

So if I have a `itemscollection` like the following:

```
{{ groupkey: 1; name: 'Ada'}, { groupkey: 1; name: 'Beda'}, {groupkey: 2; name: 'Ceda'}}
```

So after the generation of divs and labels the result should be

```
<div>
 <h3>1</h3>
 <div><label>Ada</label></div>
 <div><label>Beda</label></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <div><label>Ceda</label></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to create this or do I need to handle the creating of the elements to better construct the data to make this happen?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Does angular come with such a `unique` filter? No. Is it possible to write one? Sure. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: sounds like what you want is `groupBy` filter ... question is not clear at all though

Answer (score 1):

This filter does what you want : https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its possible by the combination of `orderBy` and `filter` function in angularJS. The following code will work :

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("lists", function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
    groupkey: 1,
    name: 'Ada'
  }, {
    groupkey: 1,
    name: 'Beda'
  }, {
    groupkey: 2,
    name: 'Ceda'
  }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="lists">
        <div ng-repeat="items in list | orderBy:'groupkey'">
            <h3>{{items.groupkey}}</h3>
                 <label>{{items.name}}</label>
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: The groupkey is repeated, that isn't what Jimmy is asking

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but something like this I guess should work

```
<div ng-repeat="items in itemcollection | unique: 'groupkey'">
  <h3>{{items.groupkey}}</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{'groupkey':  items.groupkey}:true">
     <label>{{item.name}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure the itemcollection is sorted by groupkey you may display the groupkey header only when the groupkey differs from the previous groupkey. Then you achieve to only show the groupkey header once per group. Here is an example:

```
angular.module('myapp',[]).controller("thectrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.itemcollection =  [{ groupkey: 1, name: 'Ada'}, 
                           { groupkey: 1, name: 'Beda'}, 
                           {groupkey: 2, name: 'Ceda'},
                           {groupkey: 2, name: 'D'}];
    $scope.itemcollection.sort(function(a,b) { return a.groupkey-b.groupkey;});
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="thectrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in itemcollection track by $index" >
  <h3 ng-if="$index===0 || itemcollection[$index-1].groupkey!==item.groupkey">{{item.groupkey}}</h3>

  <label>{{item.name}}</label>

 </div>
</div>
```

And a working fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/vuksyeyh/